# How to make lit components similar to native HTML?

Tags: lit-element, lit

In our lit web-components library we would like to allow users to add web components in the most HTMLwise manner. Is there a way to pass boolean attributes into components like following?

```
<custom-button disabled> // -> true 
<custom-button> // -> undefined -> (lit) false
```

Currently it looks like this:

```
<custom-button disabled="true"
```

We would like to get rid of boolean assignment and keep just word 'disabled' if it is true, the same as it is done for native HTML elements

Comment: ``setAttribute("disabled","")`` is standard JS for creating attributes without a value (booleans). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute If the tool Lit doesn't let you do that, ditch the tool

Answer (score 2):

When wanting to pass a boolean attribute in lit-html template, you can prefix the attribute with `?`.

```js
html`<custom-button ?disabled=${someBoolean}></custom-button>`;
```

Then Lit will add the attribute based on whether the expression is truthy or falsy. See docs on [boolean attributes](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#boolean-attribute-expressions).

Within the Lit component definition, you can specify a property to be boolean by providing a type

in TypeScript:

```js
class CustomButton extends LitElement {
  @property({type: Boolean})
  disabled = false;
}
```

in JavaScript:

```js
class CustomButton extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    disabled = {type: Boolean};
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

such that within the component `this.disabled` will be a boolean value based on whether the attribute exists or not.